# Is there a beta for Ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: updates, beta

I don't understand how the updates on ubuntu work and I'm wondering if there is a beta for the 17.10 update. I know it's coming out mid October but I want to try it out before then.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: the beta is due to be out today, [according to the schedule](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ArtfulAardvark/ReleaseSchedule)

Comment: 31st August 2017 which is Today

Comment: Thank you, I'll start looking at that now for when there's a new update. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can download the latest Ubuntu 17.10 daily build from the official Ubuntu image server.

[Ubuntu Kylin 17.10 (Artful Aardvark) Daily Build](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntukylin/daily-live/current/)